# JSF Converter changing option value

Tags: jsf, converters

I have a Converter and it is changing the values of all my options:

Whe I first create the `selectOneMenu` I have this `html`:

```
<select name="j_idt14:j_idt20" size="1">
        <option value="2" selected="selected">Infantil</option> //value="2"
    <option value="6">Lançamento Inverno</option>
    <option value="5">Lançamento Verão 2</option>
    <option value="4">Lançamento Preview 1</option>
    <option value="3">Feminina</option>
    <option value="7">Masculina</option>//value="7"
</select>
```

When I submit my form, it will call the converter and convert it to object, it is making some kind of mess with my values (ids), it is mostly repeating the same `id` on the first and last results.

```
<select name="j_idt14:j_idt20" size="1">
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Infantil</option>//value="2"
    <option value="6">Lançamento Inverno</option>
    <option value="5">Lançamento Verão 2</option>
    <option value="4">Lançamento Preview 1</option>
    <option value="3">Feminina</option>
    <option value="2">Masculina</option>//value="2" ?
</select>
```

Here is my `converter`

```
@FacesConverter(value = "SubGroup")
public class SubGroup implements Converter
{
    private static ProductSubgroupVO productSubgroupVO   = new ProductSubgroupVO();

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        productSubgroupVO.setId(Integer.valueOf(value));
        productSubgroupVO = (ProductSubgroupVO) new ProductSubgroupBO().getProductSubgroup(productSubgroupVO).toArray()[0];
        return (ProductSubgroupVO) productSubgroupVO;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        productSubgroupVO = (ProductSubgroupVO) value;
        String teste = String.valueOf(productSubgroupVO.getId());
        return teste;
    }
}
```

I have noticed something but I don't know if it is the correct behavior for a `converter`,  every time the `getAsObject` is called, at the end, it calls `getAsString` again.

Comment: This indicates that `getAsString()` is broken. If you show your converter logic, we may be able to point out the mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `productSubgroupVO` is declared `static` and thus shared between **all** converter instances and threads. This is not threadsafe. Remove it and declare it in the method local scope only.

```
@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
{
    ProductSubgroupVO productSubgroupVO = new ProductSubgroupVO();
    productSubgroupVO.setId(Integer.valueOf(value));
    return (ProductSubgroupVO) new ProductSubgroupBO().getProductSubgroup(productSubgroupVO).toArray()[0]
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
{
    ProductSubgroupVO productSubgroupVO = (ProductSubgroupVO) value;
    return String.valueOf(productSubgroupVO.getId());
}
```

Comment: IS it possible for the `getAsObject` return a list? My property on `ProductVO` receives a list, I have a `selectManyMenu` on my HTML.

Comment: No, that's not necessary, the converter is applied on every single item of the list. So you could just use the same converter. I understand that invoking the service/DAO on every conversion may be undesireable, you may then find https://showcase-omnifaces.rhcloud.com/showcase/converters/SelectItemsConverter.xhtml useful.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, the returned object is set on the:`<h:selectManyMenu value="#{productController.productVO.colors}"` ? Remembering that my `productVO.colors` is a `List`

Comment: Yes, that's correct. JSF will just apply the converter on every single item of the list.

Comment: So it will automatically do the `colors.add()` with the object returned from the `converter`?

Comment: Yes, that's what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Now I have this error `The class 'com.erp3.model.product.ProductVO' does not have a writable property 'colors'.` Your solution worked when I don't have to return a List. When I set a combo value on this method `public SupplierVO setSupplier()` it works but when I try to set the color on this method `public List<ColorVO> setColors()` I have this error. My `ProductVO` I have this property `private Set<ColorVO> colors;`

Comment: You need to have a valid setter for the list `public void setColors(List<ColorVO> colors)`

Comment: Here it is `public void setColors(Set<ColorVO> colors)` on my `ProductVO`

Comment: It should be a `List<ColorVO>` or `ColorVO[]`, not a `Set<ColorVO>`.

Comment: Can I use `List` to persist on Hibernate?

Comment: Thank you so much BalusC great help as usual =)